# How to make text content of a reusable navbar included in all pages to reflect

Tags: javascript, html

I included a reusuable navbar on multiple pages and it's working fine but when I tried changing the textContent of a word on same navbar, it shows undefined even when i have already declared the variable. What am I not getting right?

I wish to change the span with the id first_name to the name of the `data.first_name` in the array and I want it to reflect on every page.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("navbar.html");
  var first_name = document.getElementById("first_name");
  var data = [{
    "first_name": "Chibuogwu"
  }]

  first_name.innerHTML = data.first_name;

});
```

```html
<div class="content-side content-side-full text-center bg-black-10">
  <div class="smini-hide">
    <img class="img-avatar" src="assets/media/photos/avatar0.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="mt-2 mb-1 font-w600">
      <span id="first_name"> User</span></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives a console error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use jQuery, use jQuery

Also load is async and data is an array

```js
const data = [{
    "first_name": "Chibuogwu"
  }]

$(function() {
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("navbar.html",function() {
    $("#first_name").html(data[0].first_name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

data is an array so it should be accessed first. Please check below:

```js
 first_name.innerHTML = data[0].first_name;
```